# How to include complex Vue app inside Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a Laravel project, which should contain different Vue apps.

Some of these apps are quite-complex (stand-alone app.js file with its own components).

How can Laravel manage different vue apps, each one with its own app.js file and components?

Answer (score 1):

One approach to solve this problem is to write vue apps as SEPARATE projects (using only frontend technologies) which connect with laravel using [RESTful API](https://restfulapi.net/resource-naming/).

This is in fact simple [micro-services](https://microservices.io/) architecture (which include the hard separation between frontend and backend code). If you decide to do it, you will face [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) problem (but don't worry - you will find many solutions on internet e.g. [this](https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html)) because the vue app will be on different domain/subdomain that your RESTful laravel API.

Laravel support create restful API  [controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers) - cmd:

```
php artisan make:controller API/MovieController --api --model=Movie
```

routing `routes/api.php`:

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'v1'], function() {
   Route::apiResource('movies', 'API\MovieController');
   ...
});
```

It is good to use for api authentication [Laravel Passpor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport)t (oauth2)

You should also build your separate vue applications using some modern frontend technologies like webpack, nmp (here is some [example](https://github.com/kamil-kielczewski/vue-rich-framework) but you will probably find better)... long story - but this is good direction :)